# restart my app when press mobile home button and run again from last recently app button in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I want pause app in current scene when press home button and when run app from background load current scene and not restart my app

Answer (score 0):

On Android the home button is mapped to Keycode.Escape, just use

```
void Update()
{
 if (Input.GetKeyDown(Keycode.Escape)) DoStuff();
}
```

Comment: no , my problem is restart my app when run my app from '' recently used apps'' in android phone.